# Persistent GameManager and object Instantiation

Tags: unity-game-engine

What I'm trying to do is to make the GameManager object persistent between scenes, reading a bit I realized that the DontDestroyOnLoad() method allows this behavior, however I don't understand why it doesn't allow me to instantiate objects in new scenes.
The following code perfectly replicates the main problem:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

    public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public GameObject objectPrefab;
        private void Awake()
        {
            DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
        }
        private void Update()
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
            {
                SceneManager.LoadScene("Scene2");
                GameObject instance = Instantiate(objectPrefab);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Because the instantiated object will be destroyed when scene2 is loaded. If you want the object to be created in the new loaded scene, instantiate it in a [sceneLoaded](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager-sceneLoaded.html) event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From Unity docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html):

"*When using SceneManager.LoadScene, the scene loads in the next frame, that is it does not load immediately. This semi-asynchronous behavior can cause frame stuttering and can be confusing because load does not complete immediately.*"

The instantiation happens right away and then one frame latter scene change is triggered. So your game object is instantiated in the old scene and lives there for one frame.

As shingo proposed in the comments you can use [SceneManager.sceneLoaded](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager-sceneLoaded.html) to execute code right after a scene is loaded.